# How to work around the Queue corruption when using Process.Terminate()

Tags: python, process, queue, multiprocessing

I'm building a Python script/application which launches multiple so-called Fetchers.
They in turn do something and return data into a queue.

I want to make sure the Fetchers don't run for more than 60 seconds (because the entire application runs multiple times in one hour).

Reading the Python docs i noticed they say to be carefull when using Process.Terminate() because it can break the Queue.

My current code:

```
# Result Queue
resultQueue = Queue();

# Create Fetcher Instance
fetcher = fetcherClass()

# Create Fetcher Process List
fetcherProcesses = []

# Run Fetchers
for config in configList:
    # Create Process to encapsulate Fetcher
    log.debug("Creating Fetcher for Target: %s" % config['object_name'])
    fetcherProcess = Process(target=fetcher.Run, args=(config,resultQueue))

    log.debug("Starting Fetcher for Target: %s" % config['object_name'])
    fetcherProcess.start()
    fetcherProcesses.append((config, fetcherProcess))

# Wait for all Workers to complete
for config, fetcherProcess in fetcherProcesses:
    log.debug("Waiting for Thread to complete (%s)." % str(config['object_name']))
    fetcherProcess.join(DEFAULT_FETCHER_TIMEOUT)
    if fetcherProcess.is_alive():
        log.critical("Fetcher thread for object %s Timed Out! Terminating..." % config['object_name'])
        fetcherProcess.terminate()

# Loop thru results, and save them in RRD
while not resultQueue.empty():
    config, fetcherResult = resultQueue.get()
    result = storage.Save(config, fetcherResult)
```

I want to make sure my Queue doesn't get corrupted when one of my Fetchers times out.

What is the best way to do this?

Edit: In response to a chat with sebdelsol a few clarifications:

1) I want to start processing data as soon as possible, because otherwise i have to perform a lot of Disk Intensive operations all at once. So sleeping the main thread for X_Timeout is not an option.

2) I need to wait for the Timeout only once, but per process, so if the main thread launches  50 fetchers, and this takes a few seconds to half a minute, i need to compensate.

3) I want to make *sure* the data that comes from Queue.Get() is put there by a Fetcher that didn't timeout (since it is theoretically possible that a fetcher was putting the data in the Queue, when the timeout occured, and it was shot to death...) That data should be dumped.

It's not a very bad thing when a timeout occurs, it's not a desirable situation, but corrupt data is worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass a new `multiprocessing.Lock()` to every fetcher you start.

In the fetcher's process, be sure to wrap the `Queue.put()` with this lock:

```
with self.lock:
    self.queue.put(result)
```

When you need to terminate a fetcher's process, use its lock :

```
with fetcherLock:
    fetcherProcess.terminate()
```

This way, your queue won't get corrupted by killing a fetcher during the queue access.

Some fetcher's locks could get corrupted. But, that's not an issue since every new fetcher you launch  has a brand new lock.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

1. create a new queue and start all the fetchers that will use this
   queue.
2. have your script actually sleep the amount of time you want the fetcher's processes to have for getting a result.
3. get everything from the resultQueue - it won't be corrupted, since you didn't have to kill any process.
4. finally, terminate all fetcher's processes that are still alive.
5. loop !

Comment: It is possible for a Fetcher to timeout endlessly, so i cannot wait for an extended period to just make sure that all fetchers complete. They can crash, so i need to make _sure_.

Also, they run *multiple* times an hour (6 to be precise, every 10 minutes). And there will be 10 of these fetchers running wich will spawn about 50 Processes.

Comment: Also, even if i terminate all fetchers in the end, that doesn't mean my Queue is intact.

Comment: no but you can define a new Queue every time you loop through your script.

Comment: if your script has to end in ten minutes, before looping again, have it sleep 10 minutes. I guess I've either answered your question or you need to reformulate what's the issue.

Comment: BTW, in the answer I suggest, nothing makes sure that all fetchers complete. There's no more `join()`. In step 3 you'll only get the result for finished fetchers. that's why you have to kill the remaining ones after.

Comment: That's true if i know how many Processes timeout, and if i just wait 60 or so seconds and kill everything remaining.

But how do i finish early when all fetchers just work... I want some kind of assurance that all processes finished what they were doing, before getting all the results, or make sure that all the results i get are not corrupted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61117/discussion-between-sebdelsol-and-thijs-cramer).